# PHP PDO Prepared SELECT Statement

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I try to do a prepared SELECT statement with PDO in php. This is my statement:

```
    # named placeholders 
    $STH = $DBH->("SELECT * FROM `highscore_ranked` WHERE DeviceID = :deviceid ORDER BY Points DESC LIMIT 0 , 10");
    $STH->bindValue(':deviceid', $DeviceIDClear);

    # setting the fetch mode
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $STH->execute();
```

But I got the error:

```
 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'
```

on this line:

```
 $STH = $DBH->("SELECT * FROM `highscore_ranked` WHERE DeviceID = :deviceid ORDER BY Points DESC LIMIT 0 , 10");
```

I don't know what's wrong at this line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the name of the method!!!!

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM `highscore_ranked` WHERE DeviceID = :deviceid ORDER BY Points DESC LIMIT 0 , 10");
```

Comment: Wow that was a fast answer :)

Comment: Oh, no sry for that question. That was bad. I really didn't see that. Thanks for the answer, it works of course with method name.